# how do i fix corrupted Resources eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to create a new folder in my res, and after doing so, my whole project is filled with errors any where there is a R.drawable, or R.layout reference..  I tried running "clean project" but to no avail.. I think there is a file i need to delete and then run clean project but can't remember what it is.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your R.java class, under tour gen folder, and then building the project again.

Comment: thats the file i was looking for.. unfortunately its not there and there is only a BuildConfi.java file  oh man!  what happened.

Comment: There's probably an error in a res file, thus your R.java class cannot be recreated, and you get those errors. You'll have to find which /res file has the error, and fix it. Once is fixed, your R.java can be recreated again.

Comment: ah.. so it appears that when i tried to ad a raw folder in the res with a pop.wav file it screwed up.. that fixed it but now it begs the question how do i ad sound files to my resource with out screwing everything

Comment: Try setting them in the assets folder.

Comment: actually it was all user error.. there was a capital letter in my Pop.wav file and i often forget that "we" don't like capital letters in resource file names..  uhg.. thanks!!

Comment: Great! If that fixed your problem, please, accept the answer as valid.

Comment: Was on that.. stackoverflaw said I had to wait 2 minutes